# Is safe to set a randomly generated alpha numeric string as primary partition key and sort key in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, database

Here is the sample JSON which we are planning to insert into DynamoDB table. As of now we are having `organizationID` as primary partition key and `__id__` as sort key. Since we will query based on organizationID we kept it as primary partition key. Is it a good approach to keep `__id__` as sort key.

```
{
  "__class__": "package",
  "__updated__": "2015-10-19T14:30:13Z",
  "__created__": "2015-10-19T12:32:28Z",
  "transactions": [
    {
      transaction1
    },
    {
      transaction2
    }
  ],
  "carrier": "USPS",
  "organizationID": "6406fa6fd32393908125d4d81ec358",
  "barcode": "9400110891302408",
  "queryString": [
    "xxxxxxx",
    "YYYY",
    "delivered",    
  ],
  "deliveredTo": null,
  "__id__": "3232d1a045476786fg22dfg32b82209155b32"
}
```

Comment: As per your data model, can you have multiple items for the same organizationID? I am just trying to understand the requirement of sort key in the above data model.

Comment: Yes we will be having multiple items for the same organizationID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the best practice, you can have `timestamp` as sort key for the above data model. One advantage of having `timestamp` as sort key is that you can **sort** the data for the particular partition key and identity the latest updated item. This is the very common use case for having sort key.

It doesn't make much sense to keep both partition and sort key as **randomly generated value** because you can't use sort key efficiently (unless I miss something here).

Comment: if i keep __updated__ param as sort key then for each day(2015-10-19) per organizationID only one package data is getting inserted. If i convert "2015-10-19T14:30:13Z" to timestamp and keep it as sort key will that solve the data insert issue mentioned.

Comment: yes, please use timestamp as sort key. Keeping the date part alone would not be enough to make the item unique.